# how can i use context with setup script vue composition api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

By default I can't use this in setup
But I can use the context

How do I use it with the setup script

```
export default {
  setup(props, context) {
    // Attributes (Non-reactive object, equivalent to $attrs)
    console.log(context.attrs)
  }
}
```

This is the code used in the setup script

How do I pass the props or context with this code

```
<script setup>
console.log('hello script setup')
</script>
```

After researching, I knew that I should do this to use the props

`import { defineProps, reactive } from "vue`

But I couldn't find an alternative to **context**

Comment: There's useAttrs. If you need full context for some exotic case, use setup function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defineProps` for props and `useAttrs` if you really need those :

```
<script setup>
  import { useAttrs } from 'vue';
  const attrs = useAttrs();
  console.log(attrs);
</script>
```